# Jquery: How can I call back the same function with a different parameter after the 1st one has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function that takes in a parameter to animate it. 
I would like to call back this function with a different parameter in it after the previous one has finished. So far I have this, the animation works but it doesn't do it one after the other:

```
var thisis = document.getElementById("thisis");
var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");
var txt3 = document.getElementById("txt3");
var txt4 = document.getElementById("txt4");
var txt5 = document.getElementById("txt5");

$("#thisis").fadeIn(400, function(){
                    animetxt(txt1, function() {
                        animetxt(txt2, function(){
                            animetxt(txt3, function(){
                                animetxt(txt4, function(){
                                    animetxt(txt5);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });

function animetxt(o){ //.css and .animate on the parameter// }
```

Your help would be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `animetxt` function does not have a parameter for the callback function that you are passing to it.  Perhaps:

```
function animetxt(o, f) {
   o.animate({/* css */}, f);
}
```